# SwiftUI - How to make part of a Text Navigation Link in iOS 13?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have Two Text views containing a bold part and a not bold part added by `+` operator in SwiftUI. Like Below:

```
Text(AppStrings.dummyName)
      .bold()
+ Text(" \(AppStrings.dummyMemberRequest)")
```

I want to turn the Bold part into a NavigationLink. But it is not possible as `+` Operator only works with Text view.

How can I turn a part of the Text view into a NavigationLink in SwiftUI, iOS 13?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI tappable subtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624838/swiftui-tappable-subtext)

Comment: No. I need a NavigationLink inside the app. Not a outside website link.

Comment: The principe is the same. If you have single line text - just use `HStack`, otherwise you have to use `UIViewRepresentable` as shown in answers to that question, with an empty navigation link, which you will open using a state variable.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov is correct. If you don't know how to trigger a `NavigationLink` in code, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63367285/7129318)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550392/how-can-i-create-text-in-swiftui-with-navigationlink-only-some-words-from-text/67551315#67551315

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Markdown syntax instead of combining them like that

```swift
Text("This is a text with **bold** words")
```